# NetworkView Don't Load The Given Url Image - Localhost

Tags: android, json, android-volley, networkimageview

I'm having a problem with my `NetworkView`, I'm trying to load the image in my app, And the image url is from my localhost 127.0.0.1. But it seems its not working I only see the `networkView.setDefaultImage`.

Heres my `JSON` output of the from logcat:

[image: json]

Here' my code: `LruCacheMap.java`

```
public class LruCacheMap extends LruCache<String,Bitmap> implements ImageLoader.ImageCache{

public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    return cacheSize;
}

//CONSTRUCTOR
public LruCacheMap(){
    //put the method
    this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
}

//EQUIVALENT SIZE IN Kb
public LruCacheMap(int sizeInKiloBytes){
    super(sizeInKiloBytes);
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    put(url,bitmap);
} }
```

Here's my snippet code for my `OrgListAdapter.java`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OrgViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgType().equalsIgnoreCase("Public")){
        holder.appCompatImageViewOrgType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_type_public);
    }else {
        holder.appCompatImageViewOrgType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_private_group);
    }

    //IMAGE LOADER orgLogoName
        if (imageLoader == null) {
            imageLoader = SingletonController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            Log.e("ImageLoader Problem",imageLoader+"");
        }

        orgLogoName = mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgLogoName();
        orgLogoPath = mOrganizationData.get(position).getOrgLogoPath();
        logoUrl = orgLogoPath + orgLogoName;

        holder.networkImageViewLogo.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.picture_32px);

        if (logoUrl != null){
            Log.e("The URL: ", logoUrl);
            holder.networkImageViewLogo.setBackgroundColor(GetColorSdk.getColor(mContext,R.color.appIntroColorFifth));
            holder.networkImageViewLogo.setImageUrl(logoUrl,imageLoader);

        }else{
            holder.networkImageViewLogo.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.picture_32px);
        }
    }
```

Here's my Controller - `SingletonController.java`

```
public class SingletonController extends Application{

public static final String TAG = SingletonController.class.getSimpleName();
public Context mContext;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
LruCacheMap mLruBitmapCache;

private static SingletonController mInstance;

public SingletonController(){}

public SingletonController(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized SingletonController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    //REQUEST QUEUE
        getRequestQueue();

    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        getLruBitmapCache();
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public LruCacheMap getLruBitmapCache() {
    if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
        mLruBitmapCache = new LruCacheMap();
    return this.mLruBitmapCache;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
} }
```

I try debugging and it shows that it is not null. **I want to load the logo image in the `networkImage` .**

[image: a]

Note: I used this [one](http://newtecharticles.com/downloads/wlan-launcher/) to make my laptop as a hospot, and get the `ipV4` . My laptop serves as a Server. I'm using both emulator `(Geny Motion)` and actual device.

In my code for url: `public static final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1/organization/org_logo/" ;`

Comment: do u have server running on the Android device or are you trying to load images that are on your computer into Android?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address (also known as localhost) -- You can use this address if you are on the Server directly -- You need the Real IP address of your server In the URL for your App. To find it, From inside your Network --->  run command (ifconfig) on linux, Mac server -- (ipconfig) on a windows server  --- From Outside network you Need your WAN IP address, However you need to go on your router and to go into  Virtual Server settings (Or Port Range Forwarding) and set up a HTTP  service with the Severs IP address to forward and back HTTP requests to the server

Comment: you could save them on an actual server else where. Like on Google Cloud Storage. Or get your ip address and replace 127.0.0.1 with (your_ip_address) as mentioned above. I would also suggest using picasso, fresco or glide for loading images

Comment: @Budius - Yes, my laptop serves as my server. I use this one - http://newtecharticles.com/downloads/wlan-launcher/ . I already link them. By getting the ipv4. I'm using both emulator (Geny Motion) and actual device.

Comment: @codephillip -  I try to avoid third party libraries, I already get 64k due to many methods on third library.

Comment: @Tasos - thanks I finally get what you mean now. Many thank you.